# How to run scheduled task 3 days before end of month

Tags: windows, scheduled-tasks, windows-server-2012-r2, windows-task-scheduler, task-scheduler

Task should run 3 days before end of month, once per month.
In this year it should run in

```
Aug 29
Sept 28
Oct 29
Nov 28
Dec 29
```

How to specify this in Windows Scheduled task trigger so that it runs automatically in those days for this and next years ?

Windows Server 2012 R2 is used

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would probably create 3 tasks, or 3 triggers on a single task. One for months with 31 days, one for months with 30 days, and one for February.

Set the task trigger to monthly, select all the months for that task (30 days hath September, April, June and November). So, the 28th for those months.

As long as the tasks are not set to expire, they should keep running next year.

If you need to cover leap years, you can setup additional February triggers that last for 3 years and expire. Another trigger for Leap Year that immediately expires after use, and then yet another trigger for the next 3 years.

As described, I believe 5 triggers could cover a 7 year period.

[image]

Comment: You could do this with 1 task & multiple triggers each for monthly as you described. This works pretty well.. but what about leap years?

Comment: For leap years, probably set up the expire date for the February trigger after 3 years, a 4th trigger for leap year with immediate expiration, and then a 5th trigger for another 3 years. 5 total triggers to cover 7 years of time. Repeat as necessary.

Answer (score 0):

If you know some scripting, you can set 2 tasks.
Task1 with just one trigger on 26th of each month (the earliest your task should trigger), to run a script which gets the current month, and year, and decide whether leap or not, and when should Task2 (containing the main job) be executed.
At the end, include a `schtasks /change` command to set the date when Task2 should fire, to the calculated one.
Task2 would be triggered "At task cration/modification", with "Action" being the main program you need.